# Hold fires tap event also - KendoUI Mobile Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have an issue with KendoUI Mobile framework running on Phonegap. I use both hold and tap events, for a specific element.

My problem is that when the "hold" event gets with the "tap" event. I want that if the user holds the element it won't trigger the tap event.

```
$(element).kendoTouch({
   hold: function(e){
     alert("hold");
      e.preventDefault();
   },
   tap: function(e){
      alert("tap");
       e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

How can I get it to run only one event whether to user holds or taps the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior seems to be by design. You would probably have to set a flag in the handler for 'hold' that ignores the next 'tap'.

Answer (score 0):

The hold event will be triggered after the time passes, that which you set the time for minHold. Note: By default minHold value will be default: 800

**HTML:**

```
<a id="Check_Tap_Hold">
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#Check_Tap_Hold").kendoTouch({
                    minHold: 1000, //**set your delay time here**
                    tap: function (e) {
                        alert("tap");
                        e.preventDefault();
                    },
                    hold: function (e) {
                        alert("hold");
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
```

For reference: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/touch